# Chrome cert not importing

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

I have a cert with SAN that I want to use for my localhost projects so I can stop getting warnings from Chrome.

When I go to Settings => Advanced => Manage Certs => Personal => Import, I can import my cert and I see a message that says "The import was successful".

But I don't see the localhost cert listed in my Personal list of certs.

Why is this failing to import? OR why is it showing a success message while not showing the cert in the list of Personal certs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a self-signed certificate, it shows up under the *Trusted Root Certification Authorities* tab, not the *Personal* tab.  The latter is for client authentication certificates you use to prove your identity to a web server.